# How to handle Exception and display appropriate message using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working in MVC3 Dot Net project Using EF.

We are catching all the Exceptions in an object of Exception (i.e ex)
From this how can I get (or filter) SQlExceptions and I like to show the meaningful message.

facing problem :
I am not getting System.Data.UpdateException class

Answer (score 1):

loop through exception/inner excetion and check  if(ex is SQlException) { }
Maybe you missed adding reference to System.Data.Entity so you dont see System.Data.UpdateException class

Comment: Thank u friend i got solution for System.Data.UpdateException

Comment: If the answer was the solution, please mark it as the definitive :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be catching Exception first (or at all unless you are specifically doing something with *all* exceptions)

If you want only UpdateExceptions, then you should only catch that exception.
This catch should be above any other handlings that are more generic, for example

```
try
{
}
catch(System.Data.UpdateException ex)
{

}
catch(Exception ex) //optionally 
{
///less generic handling
}
```

Also consider for general logging ELMAH
http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: you appose is very nice but want  if (e.Exception != null) {
 if (e.Exception is SqlException) {
  SqlException sqlExcep = (SqlException)e.Exception;
  switch (sqlExcep.Number) {
   case SqlExceptionNumber.ForeignKeyConstraint:
    this.ExceptionDetails.Text += "Error : Foreign Key Violation.The Contract cannot be inserted.";
    break;
   case SqlExceptionNumber.UniqueKeyConstraint:

Comment: Post some code above I'm not fully understanding. You want to check if e.Exception is of that type rather than a thrown exception?